# OAuth error when attempting to start-host for chrome-remote-desktop on GCE

Tags: oauth, google-compute-engine, centos7, chrome-remote-desktop

I'm running CentOS 7 in a Google Compute Engine VM, and trying to connect to it via Chrome Remote Desktop.  When I run the start-host command, it fails with "OAuth error" and no more information.

I accessed the https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless site with Chrome, filled out the choices, and went through the authorization phase.  There was not an option for CentOS, so I chose "Debian" and when it gave me the connect command, I replaced the path to start-host with the CentOS one of /usr/lib64/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host, and running the resulting command fails.

I did the likely web searches and found some fairly old and unhelpful information, but nothing useful.

If I can't get Chrome Remote Desktop working, I'd be willing to try another method to run GUI-based applications (in this case, IBM's oneWEX).  I can get X11 to sort-of work remotely, but not well enough to run oneWEX.

This is the command I got from the Chrome site, modified to work with CentOS:

```
DISPLAY= /usr/lib64/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="<code>" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=
```

The start-host command asked the expected questions of the computer name and PIN, then gave the error:

```
Couldn't start host: OAuth error.
```

Comment: Having same problem... did you manage to solve it? In my case I have a debian but perhaps your fix would address my issue as well.

Comment: Never did solve it, ended up switching to TigerVNC.

Comment: In the end it work for me although I cannot tell how I (or rather it) did it. restarted the host didn't change anything but at some point latter I re-submit the registration of the host in the chrome-remote desktop webservice and this time it worked. Not sure if this is a chrome-remote-desktop server issue or a X / virtual display set up issue.

Answer (score 13):

When you get the code from https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless  it is only good for a few minutes, and only one time use. 
Just go back to https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless  follow the prompts and get a new code for every attempt.

In my case, I got another error when I first ran the command. I tried to resolve it, and reran the same command (with the original code). I kept getting the "Couldn't start host: OAuth error." until I figured out I needed to get a new code from  https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless  for each attempt.

FYI: The error message is not given right away, but after entering the computer name and double entering the pin.

Comment: I can confirm this answer. If you mess up entering the PIN, you will need to start over with a new authorization command.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1039016, this could apparently also happen if the `/usr/lib64/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host` binary is not one from the "official" DEBian package built and distributed by Google, but one built from source e.g. by yourself or your Linux distribution (such as the chrome-remote-desktop package built by Fedora; https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1788448 aims to clarify how to use that one).

Answer (score 0):

What I can see here is that you previously added some libraries to your CentOS instance, I tried replicating the error myself and inside my CentOS 7 instance (from Compute Engine) I don't seem to have any /usr/lib64/chrome-remote-desktop/ folder.

Or is it from your local machine?

Comment: Previously I had done "sudo yum install chrome-remote-desktop" to install the host software.

Comment: As the Chrome Remote Desktop indicates, there is only chance to use either Windows or Debian Linux, but you could try having a look at the following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/795703/chrome-remote-desktop-access-to-headless-ubuntu-server-16-04-machine

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and found that refreshing the headless page to get a new code string in the command worked.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.